# Python - Keras Model doesnt converge

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a network with `32` input nodes, `20` hidden nodes and `65` output nodes. My network input actually is a hash code of length `32` and the output is the word.
The input is the ascii value of each character of the Hash code. The output of the network is a binary representation I have made. Say for example `a` is equal to `00000` and `b` is equal to `00001` and so on and so forth. It only includes the alphabet and the space that why it's only `5` bits per character. I have a maximum limit of only `13` characters in my training input, so my output nodes is `13 * 5 = 65`. And Im expecting a binary output like `10101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101001011` . The bit sequence can predict at most 16 characters word given a hash code of `32` length as an input. Below is my current code:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_train_samples = scaler.fit_transform((train_samples).reshape(-1, 32))
train_labels = train_labels.reshape(-1, 65)


model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(32,), activation = 'sigmoid'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dense(25, activation='tanh'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dense(65, input_shape=(65,), activation='sigmoid')
])

overfitCallback = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=0, patience = 1000)

model.summary()
model.compile(SGD(lr=.01, decay=1e-6,  momentum=0.9),     loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_samples, train_labels, batch_size=1000, epochs=1000000, callbacks=[overfitCallback], shuffle = True, verbose=2)
```

I plan to overfit the model, so that it can memorize all the hash codes of the words in the dictionary. As an initial, my training samples is only `5,000` something. I just wanted to see if it will learn from a small dataset. How will I make network converge faster? I think its running more than one hour, and its loss function is still .5004 something and the accuracy is .7301. It gets up and down but when I check every 10 minutes or so, I can see only alittle improvement. How will I fine tune it?

UPDATE :

The training had already stopped but it didn't converge. It's loss is `.4614` and accuracy is `.7422`

Comment: I'd suggest trying the Adam optimizer using default values.  It'll self-adjust the learning rate so it tends to be the simplest way to minimize.  If Adam doesn't work, then likely you've got data that your network can't learn to represent.

Comment: @bivouac0 -> I tried already Adam, but it does not converge. May be ther's something wrong with the eay I encode the data. or the number of hidden nodes? Please guide me how to tweak it.

Comment: There's a difference between "converged" and "gives the loss I want", right?

Answer (score 1):

There are some hyper parameters that i would suggest to change first.

Try `'relu'` or `LeakyReLU()` as the activation function for the non-output layers. Basically `relu` is the standard activation function for baseline models.

The standard optimizer (for most cases) currently is Adam, try using this. Tweak its learning rate when needed. You could get better results with sgd, but it often takes a lot of epochs and a lot of hyper parameter tuning. Adam is basically the quickest (in general) optimizer to reach a 'low' loss.

To prevent overfitting you might also want to implement `Dropout(0.5)`, where the 0.5 is as an example.

Once you have reached the lowest loss, you might start changing these hyper parameters even more, to try and egt a lower loss.

Apart from this, the first thing i actually suggest is trying and add multiple hidden layers with different sizes. This might have a way larger impact then trying to optimize all the hyper parameters.

Edit: Maybe you could post a screenshot of your training loss vs epochs for the train & val data? This might make things more clear for others.